# How to sum aggregate values and get percentages?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT count (rx), class_cd
FROM RX 
GROUP BY 2
```

Results:

```
rx    class_cd
  406 C3
  430 C5
  620 OT
  773 C4
 1761 C2
13983 RX
```

Is there a way to sum up C2-C5 and Rx and OT?

Ultimately I would like to get a percentage of C2-C5 / RX-OT.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select ( sum( case when class_cd in ('C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5') then rs end ) /
         sum( case when class_cd in ('RX', 'OT') then rs end )
       ) as ratio
from t;
```

EDIT:

If you want to just count the values, then:

```
select ( sum( class_cd in ('C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5') ) /
         sum( class_cd in ('RX', 'OT') )
       ) as ratio
from t;
```

Comment: thank you, i had to do this and it worked:                                                              
          select ( sum( case when class_cd in ('C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5') then 1.000 else 0.000 end ) /
         sum( case when class_cd in ('RX', 'OT') then 1.000 else 0.000 end )
       )

Comment: @JasonM.Kluczyk . . . There is a simpler solution in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You may try aggregating by a `CASE` expression, which buckets the groups as you want:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN class_cd REGEXP '^C[2-5]$' THEN 'C2-C5',
         WHEN class_cd IN ('RX', 'OT') THEN 'RX-OT',
         ELSE class_cd END AS class_cd,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM RX
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN class_cd REGEXP '^C[2-5]$' THEN 'C2-C5',
         WHEN class_cd IN ('RX', 'OT') THEN 'RX-OT',
         ELSE class_cd END;
```